# Read from File, then write to File under same FileLock?

Tags: java, kotlin, file, locking, nio

I want to perform a read and a write under the same lock. Once the lock is acquired, I want to read the file, do some data manipulation, then write that data to the same file.

I have tried the following:

```
val storeChannel =
    FileChannel.open(
        target,
        StandardOpenOption.READ,
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE
    )
return runLocking(storeChannel) { channel ->
    val inStream = Channels.newInputStream(channel)
    val store = inStream.use { serializer.read(it) }
    val result = operation(store)
    val outStream = Channels.newOutputStream(channel)
    outStream.use { serializer.write(it, store) }
    result
}
```

(The `runLocking` function simply acquires the lock for the given channel, runs the code in curly braces, then unlocks)

However, the channel is closed after reading from it, making it impossible to write to it. I have read online that one can use `RandomAccessFile` to achieve this, but I don't want to `mmap` the whole file (which is what I assume `RandomAccessFile` does), since my writes are always sequential.

Is there a way to acquire a single Lock to do both reading and writing under? Or is `RandomAccessFile` my only option?

Comment: Why do you think `RandomAccessFile` maps the file into memory? And why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: `RandomAccessFile` does *not* `mmap()` the entire file, and you have no reason to believe otherwise. If the file is closed it is because you or something that you called closed it. You should use the `FileChannel` that you already have, rather than creating input and output streams from it.

Answer (score 0):

For locking, should you not use `FileChannel.lock`? Something like

```kotlin
fun openLocked(target: Path): FileChannel =
    FileChannel.open(
        target,
        StandardOpenOption.READ,
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE
    ).also { it.lock() }
```

See if this toy example works for you (I believe that the `use` on the derived streams in your code, close the channel)

```kotlin
    val fc =  openLocked( somePath )

    fc.use { 
        val ins = Channels.newInputStream(it)
        val store = String(ins.readBytes())

        val os = Channels.newOutputStream(it)
        os.write(" + $store".toByteArray())
    }
```